# How use the operator OR in grepl ()

Tags: r, logical-operators, grepl

I want to spot at least one of these 3 words in the string (knowing that the operator `|` do not works). And I want to also set `ignore.case=TRUE`

```
grepl(c("Cancer"|"Carcinome"|"Tumeur", c("cancer", "tuMeur", "Dysplasie", "Cancer", "Mesotheliome"),ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `grepl("Cancer|Carcinome|Tumeur", c("cancer", "tuMeur", "Dysplasie", "Cancer", "Mesotheliome"), ignore.case = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work. You need to split your OR condition without creating additional elements of your vector. You should also check the package [**stringr**](https://stringr.tidyverse.org).

```r
thevector = c("cancer", "tuMeur", "Dysplasie", "Cancer", "Mesotheliome")
thepattern = paste0( c("Cancer", "Carcinome", "Tumeur"), collapse = "|")
grepl(thepattern, thevector, ignore.case=TRUE)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>